# Mysql fetch record with find_in_set

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables 
(1) Subject 
[image]
(2) Teacher 
[image]
(3) Student 
[image]

I want record like this
[image]

I tried below query but that is not working

```
SELECT sub.name, GROUP_CONCAT( tea.name ) AS teacher,  
GROUP_CONCAT( stu.name ) AS student 
FROM subject AS sub  
LEFT JOIN teacher AS tea ON FIND_IN_SET( sub.id, tea.subject ) 
LEFT JOIN student AS stu ON FIND_IN_SET( sub.id, stu.subject ) 
GROUP BY sub.id
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can we see your work?

Comment: SELECT sub.name, GROUP_CONCAT( tea.name ) AS teacher, GROUP_CONCAT( stu.name ) AS student
FROM subject AS sub
LEFT JOIN teacher AS tea ON FIND_IN_SET( sub.id, tea.subject )
LEFT JOIN student AS stu ON FIND_IN_SET( sub.id, stu.subject )
GROUP BY sub.id

Comment: ^--« place that in your question, not in comments.

Comment: What do you mean, "not working" ? What error do you get ? Or why are the results not the expected ones ?

Comment: I tried my query but with that query i didn't got my expected data

Comment: Word of advice: *Don't* store multiple values in a single field.  Please normalize your database.  Create a link table.  You'll thank me later.

Comment: This has to be normalized. Work on your schema first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things become unnecessary complicated when the DB design is not proper and on the top of that storing data as comma separated string is a real bad idea.

The first thing you should do is to normalize the data, which will make life simple and even query will be optimized.

However in the current situation you can try as

```
select 
subject,
group_concat(distinct teacher_name) as teacher_name,
group_concat(distinct student_name) as student_name
from
(
  select
  s.name as subject,
  t.name as teacher_name,
  st.name as student_name
  from 
  subject s
  left join teacher t on find_in_set(s.id,t.subject)
  left join student st on find_in_set(s.id,st.subject)
)x
group by subject;
```

**[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38b3e/15)**

Comment: To the OP, please normalize so you don't have to deal with subqueries.

Comment: Thanks #Abhik Chakraborty.